# How to ensure that Wordpress child theme get security updates when parent theme gets updated

Tags: wordpress, security, child-theming

I am setting up child themes for my WP site to do minor customisation to the layout of the parent.

Mostly in these files:

- category.php
- header.php
- footer.php

My coding skills are amateurish at best so likely won't touch those function.php files.

However, I am concerned about the compromise of security when there is a security update in the parent theme.

What can I do to ensure that the security is not compromised?

Comment: As long as you are not changing any functions and you are only calling functions in your templates, I can't think of any security problems that wouldn't be fixed when you update your theme.

Comment: Thanks .. it means that there should not likely be any security vulnerability in those category, header, footer types of file?

Comment: Yes. Professionally build Wordpress theme template files only ever call functions in my experience.

Comment: Noted. Thanks mate!